# Wordpress multiple single post templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type called funerals and a page the lists all the funeral posts. To display a single page I created a file called single-funerals.php and that all works well. But, now I need to have another single post page that only displays a video for a particular funeral. How would I set that up and link to it from the main page that lists all the posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your args include:

   'capability_type'  => 'page',

   'hierarchical'     => true,

   'supports'          => array( 'page-attributes' ),

---

2. Add the relevant php (not the example cpt registration) to very bottom of your functions.php file or outside of all other functions or use a functions plugin. Rename slugs/functions, etc., as necessary. If you have another template for the single child, see the very bottom of the code example.

---

3. Make your CPT item parent.

---

4. Add the shortcode `[get-child-page-links]` below to make a link from the parent to the child.

---

5. Make your CPT item child. Choose the parent in the Page Attributes meta box.

---

**PHP**

```
/**  
 *
 * Register your CPT. This is not complete code
 *
 * If you want to have a child page of a CPT single make sure that the $args includes:
 *
 * 'capability_type' => 'page',
 * 'hierarchical'    => true,  
 * 'supports'        => array( 'page-attributes' ),
 */
function myprefix_register_mycpts() {

    /**
     * Post Type: MyCpt
     */

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'MyCpts', '' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'MyCpt', '' ),
    );

    $args = array(

        //... indicates others

        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical'    => true, 
        'supports'        => array( 'page-attributes' ),

    );

    register_post_type( 'mycpt', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'myprefix_register_mycpts' );


/**  
 * 
 * Shortcode
 * Get the Child Links
 * Use CSS to style the .child-link-pages class and its children
 *
 * usage: [get-child-page-links]
 * By: me
 *
 */
function yourprefix_get_child_pages() { 

    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => 'any',
        'posts_per_page'      => -1,
        'post_parent'         => $post->ID,
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'orderby'             => 'menu_order',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    );

    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );
    $output = '';

    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : 

        $output .= '<ul class="child-page-links">';

        while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); 

            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= '<a class="button" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
            $output .= get_the_title();
            $output .= '</a>';
            $output .= '</li>';

        endwhile;

        $output .= '</ul>';

    endif; 
    wp_reset_postdata();

    //shortcodes return not echo!
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode('get-child-page-links', 'yourprefix_get_child_pages' );



/**  
 *
 * Set the child template for a CPT
 * https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include
 * http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145188/64742
 * by Toscho -- awesome!
 *
 * change mycpt to yours
 *
 */
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {

    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return $template; // not single

    if ( 'mycpt' !== get_post_type() )
        return $template; // wrong post type

    if ( 0 === get_post()->post_parent )
        return $template; // not a child

    return locate_template( 'single-child-mycpt.php' );
} );
```

Comment: This would probably work, but it looks like if you have over 5000 (which I will) it will cause major site speed issues.

Comment: The template include, by Toshco (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) won't cause a site speed issue. The loop won't cause an issue (the shortcode loop), and the adding args to the CPT also won't be an issue with speed. So what are you basing this statement on?

Comment: You have 5000 child pages? A better solution would be to use ajax load to get the video or even just use a lightbox to load the video on the same page.